# How to most efficiently calculate daily enrollment from an entry and exit date in R?

Tags: r, purrr, intervals, lubridate

The following code works, but it seems highly inefficient. Is there a more straight forward way to calculate a daily enrollment by site from an entry and exit date.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
id <- seq_along(1:10),
entry_date <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-10"), by = 1),
exit_date <- seq(as.Date("2022-05-20"), as.Date("2022-05-30"), by = 1),
site <- rep(c("Loc1", "Loc2"), times= 5)
) %>% 
  set_names("id", "entry_date", "exit_date", "site") %>% 
  mutate(exit_date = as.character(exit_date))

df[8:10, 3] <- rep("NA", times = 3)
```

Create a ytd sequence:

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), today(), by = 1)
```

And iterate the function below over it with:

```
enrolled_ytd <- map_dfr(date, ~ daily_enrollment_fun(.), .id = "date")
```

Function:

```
daily_enrollment_fun <- function(date){
  df %>% 
    select(id, entry_date, exit_date, site) %>% 
    drop_na(site) %>%
    mutate(enrolled_int = interval((entry_date), (exit_date))) %>% 
    distinct(id, .keep_all = T) %>% 
    mutate(enrolled = date %within% enrolled_int) 
}
```

The output is a dataframe with a TRUE/FALSE enrollment for every id and every day in the sequence of dates.
To clean the data, I run the function:

```
daily_enrollment_clean_fun <- function(date, origin = "2022-01-01") {
  
  enrolled_ytd  %>% 
    mutate(date = as.numeric(date) -1,
           date = as.Date(date, origin = origin)) %>%
    group_by(date, site, enrolled) %>%
    count() %>%
    filter(enrolled == "TRUE") %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-enrolled) %>% 
    arrange(desc(date))
}
```

Comment: [I think your example data needs 10 exit days, not 11.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you what you're looking for? I expect this should be more performant since the calculation here is vectorized once we get the stream of entries and exits into a longer form.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(entry_date:exit_date) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(name == "entry_date", 1, -1)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  arrange(site, value) %>%
  mutate(enrollment = cumsum(change))  %>%
  complete(value = seq.Date(min(value, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                  max(value, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                  by = "day")) %>%
  fill(enrollment) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result into ggplot with `%>% ggplot(aes(value, enrollment, color = site)) + geom_point()`

[image]

---

Modified input (to keep both date columns as dates)

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  id <- seq_along(1:10),
  entry_date <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-10"), by = 1),
  exit_date <- seq(as.Date("2022-05-21"), as.Date("2022-05-30"), by = 1),
  site <- rep(c("Loc1", "Loc2"), times= 5)
) %>% 
  set_names("id", "entry_date", "exit_date", "site")

df[8:10, 3] <- rep(NA_real_, times = 3)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works and is much more efficient! How could the fill argument extend to 'today' so that it could be a function with an input for a date range? I need to enter a date range and see enrollment by site.

Comment: I think you could drop in `Sys.Date()` in place of `max(value, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient approach using `data.table`

- setDT()
- update missing exit_date to be equal to the final date in `date`
- join on the combination (`CJ`) of id and date values, by id
- set enrollment equal to the sum of rows where `date` falls within the entry and exit date, by date and site

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(exit_date), exit_date:=max(date)][CJ(date,id=df$id), on=.(id)][
  , .(enrollment= sum(date>=entry_date & date<=exit_date)), by=.(date,site)]
```

Output:

```
           date site enrollment
  1: 2022-01-01 Loc1          1
  2: 2022-01-01 Loc2          0
  3: 2022-01-02 Loc1          1
  4: 2022-01-02 Loc2          1
  5: 2022-01-03 Loc1          2
 ---                           
286: 2022-05-23 Loc2          4
287: 2022-05-24 Loc1          3
288: 2022-05-24 Loc2          4
289: 2022-05-25 Loc1          3
290: 2022-05-25 Loc2          3
```

Input Data:

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  id <- seq_along(1:10),
  entry_date <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-10"), by = 1),
  exit_date <- seq(as.Date("2022-05-21"), as.Date("2022-05-30"), by = 1),
  site <- rep(c("Loc1", "Loc2"), times= 5)
) %>% 
  set_names("id", "entry_date", "exit_date", "site") %>% 
  mutate(exit_date = as.character(exit_date))

df[8:10, 3] <- rep("NA", times = 3)
date <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), lubridate::today(), by = 1
```